# Django form not registering user, even though all fields are valid

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Within this app, I am presenting users with a registration form in which they enter their username, password, confirm their password (this confirmation is not part of the form, rather a check I do to ensure the passwords match in views.py), and their email. For some reason, whenever I attempt to register a with a the wrong confirmation password I keep getting the error "Something went wrong... Please try again!" in my else block instead of "passwords must match". I am pretty stuck and not sure what went wrong as before this functionality was fully operational and I started working on other features for my app.

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            confirmation = request.POST['confirmation']

            # Ensure password matches confirmation
            if password != confirmation:
                messages.error(request, 'Passwords must match.')
                return render(request, "network/register.html", {
                    "register_form": form
                })

            # Attempt to create new user
            try:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
                user.save()
            except IntegrityError:
                messages.error(request, 'Username already taken.')
                return render(request, "network/register.html", {
                    "register_form": form
                })
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            # Always returns this whenever submitted
            messages.error(request, 'Something went wrong... Please try again!')
            return render(request, "network/register.html", {
                "register_form": form
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "network/register.html", {
            "register_form": UserRegistrationForm()
        })
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserRegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']

        widgets = {
            'username': TextInput(
                attrs={'class': 'input form-control', "placeholder": "Username", 'autocomplete': 'off'}),
            'password': TextInput(
                attrs={'class': 'input form-control', "type": 'password', "placeholder": "Password", 'autocomplete': 'off'}),
            'email': TextInput(
                attrs={"class": "input form-control", "type": 'email', "placeholder": "johndoe@gmail.com", 'autocomplete': 'off'}),
        }
```

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser, models.Model):
    pass
```

**register.html**

```
<!--Form section-->
    <div class="sign-up-section">
        <h2 class="title text-center">Sign Up</h2>
        <div class="sign-up-card">

            <form action= "{% url 'register' %}" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data' class='form'>

                {% csrf_token %}
                
                <div class="input-group">
                    <img class="form-icon" src={% static "icons/profile-user.svg" %}>
                    {{register_form.username}}
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <img class="form-icon" src={% static "icons/key.svg" %}>
                    {{register_form.password}}
                </div>
                <!-- The confirmation will not be part of the Model form, rather just something else to input and compare -->
                <div class="input-group">
                    <img class="form-icon" src={% static "icons/key.svg" %}>
                    <input type="password" name="confirmation" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <img class="form-icon" src={% static "icons/envelope.png" %}>
                    {{register_form.email}}
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary create-button" type="submit" value="Create Account">
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

There are no traceback errors associated with this problem, just the logic doesn't allow me to register a user/ throw the correct error when the confirmation doesn't match the original password.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do it the right way, one of your field is in your Form and the other one is not. In the end you have one which is cleaned and the other one is not. As well you do your Form check in your view.

Let's clear it a bit:

forms.py

```py
class UserRegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    confirmation = forms.CharField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'confirmation']
        widgets = {
            'username': TextInput(
                attrs={'class': 'input form-control', "placeholder": "Username", 'autocomplete': 'off'}),
            'password': PasswordInput(
                attrs={'class': 'input form-control', "type": 'password', "placeholder": "Password", 'autocomplete': 'off'}),
            'confirmation': PasswordInput(
                attrs={'class': 'input form-control', "type": 'password', "placeholder": "Confirm your password", 'autocomplete': 'off'}),
            'email': TextInput(
                attrs={"class": "input form-control", "type": 'email', "placeholder": "johndoe@gmail.com", 'autocomplete': 'off'}),
        }

    # let's validate your form in a form validation method
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if cleaned_data['password'] != cleaned_data['confirmation']:
                self.add_error('password', "Your password is different from the confirmation!")
```

Now your password validation is done in the Form which means the call of .is_valid() will return False if the passwords are not the same and load the error message in the form. You can make your view lighter now:

views.py:

```py
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           user = form.save() # this will put an error in case the username is taken and will be brought back in the form to display on your template
           login(request, user) #This is a VERY bad idea to login on register
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            # Always returns this whenever submitted
            messages.error(request, 'Something went wrong... Check the form for more informations')
            return render(request, "network/register.html", {
                "register_form": form
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "network/register.html", {
            "register_form": UserRegistrationForm()
        })
```

Finally, you should display the errors in your template to know what is the problem exactly, Django form keep the error messages return by Form and Model validation. You can make it pretty but if you want to see them for debug you can add in your template:

```html
{% if form.errors %}
<div id="form-error">
    <p>errors list:</p>
    <ul>
    {% for field in register_form %}
    <li>{{ field.errors|striptags }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

That will show which validation failed.

About the unique username you have 2 options, one is better than the other (as usual)

1st method (the best one) you can redefine the username field in your model to make it unique:

```py
class User(AbstractUser, models.Model):
    username = models.Charfield(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

That way on the form validation, the model will raise an exception caught by the form which will return it as a Form error.

Second solution, in the clean of your form you can check for it:

```py
def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if cleaned_data['password'] != cleaned_data['confirmation']:
                self.add_error('password', "Your password is different from the confirmation!")
        if User.objects.filter(username=cleaned_data['username']).exists():
            self.add_error('username', "Username already taken")
```

But I hardly recommand you to use the first solution which is better in terms of efficiency.

To display the errors in your template, you can use to display the field related errors.

```html
<ul class="text-danger list-unstyled">
    {% for error in yourform.yourfieldname.errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

At the same time you will win a lot of time if you use the display of the complete form not field by field.

Comment: How would I then present the "Username already taken." message to the user if my views.py is simplified? is there a way to check whether the username already exists in the model through the clean() method? Also, how come its a bad idea to directly login users after they've registered? I'm relatively new to Django and just curious

Comment: Also after implementing the solution, the code is able to return the form without having the confirmation field filled in (if it doesn't match the password), but when I enter the correct password it just repeats that process again, asking for the confirmation without registering the user. And also, the form.errors are not being displayed

Comment: For your first question: I edited my answer.
For the 2nd one: It's a bad idea for few reasons, First, because most of the time you want to ask confirmation of the email address before allow to login, second, that means a bot can just subscribe and will be auto logged in on your website. As well if the user make a mistake in the password, it will not realise it before doing some stuff which can be a lost of time for him.

For your third point, I'm not sure to understand, you mean that if you put 2 different passwords or the same in both case it returns a wrong password error?

Comment: For the error display, you have to put it in your template to display it. Errors fields are not displayed when you put fields one by one. I edited my answer to put an example of error display.